# How do I determine if the linux password was changed?

Tags: centos, rhel, password

I'm developing an application which is distributed on a VM. The default password is always the same, but it's hash in `/etc/shadow` changes with every release. How can I programmatically (e.g., from a `bash` script) find out whether the password was changed? Checking the hash is not an option because if the password was changed to something else and back, it will be different. I also want to keep the check as simple as possible.

Comment: `chage -l <user>` should give you this information.

Comment: you passwd are in the md5 form (e.g. $1$salt$nWwtt7njwVig74jTAfjuG/ ) ?

Comment: No, they are like this only when changed. This is actually one of the options I'm considering, to check for length/structure. They look like this: 8yInpa/Ksc9wA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the passwd, you can generate de md5 string with

```
 openssl passwd -salt $salt -1 foo
```

The point is getting the value for "$salt". This can be retrieved using awk on the crypted passwd from `/etc/shadow`.

```
 echo $CRYPTIC | awk -F\$ '{print $3}'
```